# INSERT Multiple rows to DB using POST AJAX Call and Asp.net web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, post, asp.net-web-api

I am using Cordova with VS2015 and trying to insert multiple rows to database using POST AJAX call. I am able to insert one record at a time but getting error when trying to insert multiple rows at a time. Also, I am able to insert multiple records using fiddler and Service  but not able to insert using my application. Any suggestions are helpful.

Below is what I have:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {

                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CONTAINER_SCAN_LOG", [], function (tx, res) {

                    var ScanlogData = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = res.rows.item(i)
                        ScanlogData[i] = {
                            CONTAINER_SCAN_LOG_ID: row['CONTAINER_SCAN_LOG_ID'],
                            SCANNED_BATCH: row['SCANNED_BATCH']
                        }
                    }                   

                    var datastring = JSON.stringify(ScanlogData).replace(/]|[[]/g, '');


                        $.ajax({

                            type: "POST",                                
                            url: "http://localhost/ValidateTagsService/api/ScanLog",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            crossDomain: true,

                            data: datastring
                            ,
                            success: function (result) {

                                alert("Uploaded to Service");


                            },
                            error: function () {
                               //Error Code
                            }

                        })                                          
                })
            })
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message you're seeing?

Comment: @sherb error :  input string not in correct format.

Comment: Can you provide the class you're using to model in the Web API, the Controller and the Request Body?